# How do I query a List in a Class?

Tags: soql, class

I'm building a class to lookup all of a Contact's Interaction_*c records.
Using a Contact.Id value, I'll populate a List of all Interaction*_c records.
When I have all of the Contact's records I want to repeatedly query the List for various records in it.  I intend to re-query this List with at least 10 different ways.

I believe I have built the list correctly but I don't understand how to query the list itself.  I'm trying to format 'Step 3' correctly.

Thanks,

Kevin

```
    public with sharing class InteractionValuesTest {

// Step 1 - Accept an input of a ContactID.
// Step 2 - Create a local Interaction list to hold all Interaction values of the Contact.
// Step 3 - Query the list and gather stats as necessary

//Step 1
public void InteractionsByContact(Contact con){

    Integer AdvancementCorrespondenceCount;



    //Step 2
    List<Interaction__c> interactions = [Select i.Sub_type__c, i.Start_Date_Time__c, i.Selected_Sub_type__c, i.SEM_Code__c, 
                                        i.RowCountValue__c, i.Registration_ID__c, i.Program_Type__c, i.Participant__c, i.Name, i.IsDeleted, i.Interaction_Type__c, 
                                        i.Id, i.ExecEd_Program_Name__c, i.End_Date_Time__c, i.Description__c, i.Contact__c, i.Company_Name__c 
                                        From Interaction__c i 
                                        Where i.IsDeleted = false and Contact__c = :con.Id];

    //Step 3
    AdvancementCorrespondenceCount = [SELECT count(i.RowCountValue__c) FROM interactions];

    }
}
```

Thanks sfdcfox,

Got ya on the alias.
Got ya on the IsDeleted.

Accepting a list of contacts: I think I would structure the method something like this: 
public void InteractionValuesTest (List con){}

I believe I see what you are doing with the maps, I understand they are more versatile than a List.  I need to study up on those.

As far as the multiple querying, the complete Contact Interactions list I pull back per Contact gives me answers to the different types of programs students have attended for example.  I know I shouldn’t query the database repeatedly, that's why I was trying to re-query the List.  Processing the data in various ways is a bit tricky.  Looks like I should get the data inside the 'for' loop.

Thanks,

Kevin

Just to illustrate, this is my working trigger I want to replace.  It's ugly but it works, I want it to be efficient, I know this is not!!!

```
trigger ContactInteractions on Interaction__c   (after insert, after update, after delete) {

// Update Multiple Contact and Account fields: TBD, when an Affiliation record is inserted, updated or deleted. 

Integer AdvancementCorrespondenceCount;
Integer AdvancementMeetingCount;
Integer AdvancementVisitsCount;
Integer AlumniAttendEventsCount;
Integer AlumniGivingCount;
Integer AlumniSpeakingRecordCount;
Integer CDCCorrespondenceCount;
Integer CDCSpeakingRecordCount;
Integer ExecEdSpeakingRecordCount;
Integer ExecEdRegistrationCount;
Integer ExecEdAttendEventsCount;
Integer ExecEdCustomClientCount;
Integer ExecEdCustomerCount;
Integer ExecEdCustomClientContactCount;
Integer ExecEdCustomerContactCount;
string ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE;
Boolean ExecEdCustomClient;
Boolean ExecEdCustomer;
Boolean ExecEdCustomClientContact;
Boolean ExecEdCustomerContact;

try {

// Store Contact record ID
map< id, contact > contacts = new map< id, contact >();
map< id, account > accounts = new map< id, account >();

if (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate) 
    {

       // Create trigger for new or selected Interaction__c  record
       for(Interaction__c  record:trigger.new)        
       {

           // Advancement Correspondence Count
           AdvancementCorrespondenceCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Correspondence'];

           // Advancement Meeting Count
           AdvancementMeetingCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Meeting'];

           // Advancement Visits Count
           AdvancementVisitsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Visit'];

           // Alumni Attend Events Count
           AlumniAttendEventsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Attend Event'];

           // Alumni Giving Count
           AlumniGivingCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Giving'];

           // Alumni Speaker count
           AlumniSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // CDC Interaction Speaker count
           CDCSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'CDC_Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // CDC Correspondence Count
           CDCCorrespondenceCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'CDC_Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Correspondence'];

           // ExecEd Speaker count
           ExecEdSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // ExecEd Registration Count
           ExecEdRegistrationCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Registration'];

           // Exed Attend Events Count
           ExecEdAttendEventsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Attend Event'];

           // ExecEd Custom Client Count
           ExecEdCustomClientContactCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Custom'];

               if(ExecEdCustomClientContactCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomClientContact = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomClientContact = FALSE;
               }   

           // ExecEd Open Client Count
           ExecEdCustomerContactCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Open'];

               if(ExecEdCustomerContactCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomerContact = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomerContact = FALSE;
               }   

            // Most Recent Contact ExecEd SEM Code
            List<Interaction__c> codes = [SELECT SEM_Code__c FROM Interaction__c WHERE Contact__c = :record.Contact__c AND SEM_Code__c != null ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c DESC LIMIT 1];

            if (codes.isEmpty()) 
                ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = '';
            else {
                ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = codes[0].SEM_Code__c;
            }


        // Account field updates:

           // ExecEd Custom Client Count
           ExecEdCustomClientCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Account__c = :record.Account__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Custom'];

               if(ExecEdCustomClientCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomClient = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomClient = FALSE;
               }   

           // ExecEd Open Client Count
           ExecEdCustomerCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Account__c = :record.Account__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Open'];

               if(ExecEdCustomerCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomer = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomer = FALSE;
               }   

           // Contact update record  
           contacts.put(record.contact__c, new contact(id=record.contact__c, CDC_Guest_Speaker__c = CDCSpeakingRecordCount,
           IntAASpeakingCnt__c = AlumniSpeakingRecordCount, ExecEd_Guest_Speaker__c = ExecEdSpeakingRecordCount,
           CDC_Correspondence__c = CDCCorrespondenceCount, Advancement_Correspondence__c = AdvancementCorrespondenceCount,
           Advancement_Meetings__c = AdvancementMeetingCount, Advancement_Visits__c = AdvancementVisitsCount,
           Alumni_Attend_Event__c = AlumniAttendEventsCount, ExecEd_Register__c = ExecEdRegistrationCount,
           ExecEd_Attend__c = ExecEdAttendEventsCount, Alumn_Giving__c = AlumniGivingCount,
           ExecEd_Custom_Client__c = ExecEdCustomClientContact, ExecEd_Open_Client__c = ExecEdCustomerContact,
           ExecEd_SEM_Code__c = ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE));

           // Update Contact record
           update contacts.values(); 


           // Account data to update           
           accounts.put(record.Account__c, new account(id=record.Account__c, ExecEd_Custom_Client__c = ExecEdCustomClient, ExecEd_Customer__c = ExecEdCustomer ));  

           // Update Account record
           update accounts.values(); 

        }   
    }

if (trigger.isdelete) 
    {

       // Create trigger for deleted npe5__Affiliation__c  record
       for(Interaction__c  record:trigger.old)        
       {

           // Advancement Correspondence Count
           AdvancementCorrespondenceCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Correspondence'];

           // Advancement Meeting Count
           AdvancementMeetingCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Meeting'];

           // Advancement Visits Count
           AdvancementVisitsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Visit'];

           // Alumni Attend Events Count
           AlumniAttendEventsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Attend Event'];

           // Alumni Giving Count
           AlumniGivingCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Giving'];

           // Alumni Speaker count
           AlumniSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND (Interaction_Type__c = 'Advancement Interaction' OR Interaction_Type__c = 'Alumni Interaction') 
           AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // CDC Interaction Speaker count
           CDCSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'CDC_Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // CDC Correspondence Count
           CDCCorrespondenceCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'CDC_Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Correspondence'];

           // ExecEd Speaker count
           ExecEdSpeakingRecordCount = [select count() from Interaction__c  where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Speaker'];

           // ExecEd Registration Count
           ExecEdRegistrationCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c 
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Registration'];

           // Exed Attend Events Count
           ExecEdAttendEventsCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Selected_Sub_type__c = 'Attend Event'];

           // ExecEd Custom Client Count
           ExecEdCustomClientContactCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Custom'];

               if(ExecEdCustomClientContactCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomClientContact = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomClientContact = FALSE;
               }   

           // ExecEd Open Client Count
           ExecEdCustomerContactCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Contact__c = :record.Contact__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Open'];

               if(ExecEdCustomerContactCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomerContact = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomerContact = FALSE;
               }   

            // Most Recent Contact ExecEd SEM Code
            List<Interaction__c> codes = [SELECT SEM_Code__c FROM Interaction__c WHERE Contact__c = :record.Contact__c AND SEM_Code__c != null ORDER BY Start_Date_Time__c DESC LIMIT 1];

            if (codes.isEmpty()) 
                ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = '';
            else {
                ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE = codes[0].SEM_Code__c;
            }


           // Account field updates:

           // ExecEd Custom Client Count
           ExecEdCustomClientCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Account__c = :record.Account__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Custom'];

               if(ExecEdCustomClientCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomClient = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomClient = FALSE;
               }   

           // Exed Attend Events Count
           ExecEdCustomerCount = [select count() from Interaction__c where Account__c = :record.Account__c
           AND Interaction_Type__c = 'ExecEd Interaction' AND Program_Type__c = 'Open'];

               if(ExecEdCustomerCount >= 1)
                   ExecEdCustomer = TRUE;
               Else {
                   ExecEdCustomer = FALSE;
               }   

           // Contact update record  
           contacts.put(record.contact__c, new contact(id=record.contact__c, CDC_Guest_Speaker__c = CDCSpeakingRecordCount,
           IntAASpeakingCnt__c = AlumniSpeakingRecordCount, ExecEd_Guest_Speaker__c = ExecEdSpeakingRecordCount,
           CDC_Correspondence__c = CDCCorrespondenceCount, Advancement_Correspondence__c = AdvancementCorrespondenceCount,
           Advancement_Meetings__c = AdvancementMeetingCount, Advancement_Visits__c = AdvancementVisitsCount,
           Alumni_Attend_Event__c = AlumniAttendEventsCount, ExecEd_Register__c = ExecEdRegistrationCount,
           ExecEd_Attend__c = ExecEdAttendEventsCount, Alumn_Giving__c = AlumniGivingCount,
           ExecEd_Custom_Client__c = ExecEdCustomClientContact, ExecEd_Open_Client__c = ExecEdCustomerContact,
           ExecEd_SEM_Code__c = string.valueof(ExecEdCustomerSEMCODE)));

           // Update Contact record
           update contacts.values(); 

           // Account data to update           
           accounts.put(record.Account__c, new account(id=record.Account__c, ExecEd_Custom_Client__c = ExecEdCustomClient, ExecEd_Customer__c = ExecEdCustomer ));  

           // Update Account record
           update accounts.values(); 

       }   
    }

    } 
catch (Exception e) {

}    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the number of records, just ask for the size of the list:

```
AdvancementCorrespondenceCount = interactions.size();
```

Some other notes:

- The alias *i* isn't necessary in this type of query, and just makes it bigger than it should be.
- Anything inside `[...]` is a query, and the result of a query is a list; Step 2, as you have defined it, is a query, not a list constructor (which would have been simply `new List<Interaction__c>()`.
- Don't query multiple times for the "same" data. Queries per transaction are limited. You can get all the data in one pass, then process that data in various ways.
- You might consider accepting a *list* of contact IDs, in order to make the code bulk-friendly. You can use a *map* to keep track of which interactions belong to which contact.
- You don't need to actually use `IsDeleted = false`, because this is a normal query, not a "queryAll" call (which would be `[SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ALL ROWS]`). Technically, this doesn't hurt, but it could cause confusion to later maintainers.

Here's a new starting point for you:

```
public void InteractionsByContact(Set<Id> contactIds){
    Map<Id, Interaction__c[]> interactions = new Map<Id, Interaction__c[]>();
    for(Id contactId: contactIds)
        interactions.put(contactId, new Interaction__c[0]);
    for(Interaction__c interaction: [SELECT Id, Sub_Type__c, Start_Date_Time__c, 
                                            Selected_SUb_Type__c, SEM_Code__c,
                                            RowCountValue__c, Registration_Id__c, 
                                            Program_Type__c, Participant__c, Name, 
                                            Interaction_Type__c, ExecEd_Program_Name__c, 
                                            End_Date_Time__c, Description__c, Contact__c, 
                                            Contact_Name__c 
                                     FROM   Interaction__c
                                     WHERE  Contact__c IN :contactIds]) {
        interactions.get(interaction.contact__c).add(interaction);
    }
    // At this point, interactions.get(contactId).size() represents the number of
    // interactions *per contact*.
}
```

Comment: sfdcfox, I made edits to my question above to explain as much as I could.  I'm going to attempt to try your idea using the Maps and for statements.  Thanks!